# Setting a bearer JWT token in Angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, jwt, bearer-token

I am currently getting a 401 unauthorized error in the console for trying to access an API endpoint I built, which is protected. I noticed that I did not add the bearer token to the header.

I noticed this and added this in however I am still getting the 401 error, what am I doing wrong? I know the token is valid because I am testing in Postman and I get a 200 response code in Postman, but 401 in Angular.

Here is my code:

```
let token = localstorage.get('token');

  getCategories() : Observable<any> {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token");

    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

    
    return this.http.get(this.CategoriesUrl, { headers: headers} )
  }
```

Comment: Did you verify if the correct token is being sent in the header? I mean are you getting correct value from the local storage?

Comment: yes i even copied the token from loca; storage and inserted into postman to test which gives me back the data from the endpoint

Comment: Looks like Your code is not using the same token as you are using in postman... You only can verify that by debugging your code ..

Comment: debugged and printed the token and copied into postman same token string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instances of the new **HttpHeader** class are immutable objects. Invoking class methods will return a new instance as result. So , you need to do the following:

```
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  header = header.set('Auth', 'Bearer ' + token )
```

Comment: yes this is correct, however Auth needs to be replaced with Authorization, but besides that works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Set` vs `Append` - use append.

> The append method appends a new value to the existing set of values for a header and returns a new instance. The append method does not check if the value exists.

> The Sets method returns a new instance after modifying the given header. If the header already exists, its value is replaced with the given value in the returned object.

```js
 headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
```

Though I would suggest making an interceptor, to set the header for all queries.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { environment } from '@environments/environment';
import { AuthenticationService } from '@app/_services';

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            
            const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
                }
            });
        

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried using append and still getting 401 unauthorised error code

Comment: From console inspector, please post your request. https://mkyong.com/computer-tips/how-to-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome/